# How to retrain a machine learning model in python till we get desired outcome

Tags: python, machine-learning, training-data, topic-modeling

I am building a topic model for customer feedbacks using the Non-Negative Matrix Factorization (NMF) topic model.

Which creates topic clusters as follows:

```
[(0, [u'reserved block', u'reserved block available', u'reserved block week', u'need reserved block']), (1, [u'hour block', u'package hour block', u'bring hour block', u'bring hour']), (2, [u'hard block', u'driver hard block', u'driver hard', u'gps horrible']), (3, [u'delivery block', u'hard delivery block', u'hard delivery', u'delivery block available']), (4, [u'block available', u'reserved block available', u'make block', u'make block available'])
```

But, topic 0&4 and topic 2&3 are pretty much the same. I want to know how I can re-train the model so that it takes topic 0 & 4; topic 2 & 3 as one topic taking union of the keywords in both (& setting weights to them on the basis of their order & the ones those are common should also be given more weight).

Answer (score 0):

In general, if output of your NMF or LDA or other similar algorithm gives you a set of topics with some overlap first recommendation is simple - decrease number of topics. By doing this you naturally force algorithm to merge similar topics together. I would advice to try this and check the outcome.

If you still want to manually mess with the results of the algorithm training and manually merge several topics together I would try to start with reading documentation on the specific algorithm you are using (NMF) and checking which of attributes define specific topics (attribute is called components_) and the words which define the topic. Then you may just update existing NMF instance to adjust its components. Though it will be a rather difficult task.

**UPDATED**

Another approach is to take the document to topic and word to topic matrixes (which are technically outputs of the algorithms) and manually update them. Check the article:

https://medium.com/towards-data-science/improving-the-interpretation-of-topic-models-87fd2ee3847d

In general, as the result of NMF you should get a 2 matrixes. One of them will show degree of membership of each document to each topic. Another - word weights towards each topic.

When merging 2 topics you want to:

1) Merge columns for topics in the document to topic matrix. For example if in this matrix you have a row which shows a document which had 50% membership for topic 1 and 10% membership for topic 2 as the result of merge you probably should obtain the membership to merged topic of 60%

2) Merge rows for topics in the word to topic matrix. That's where it becomes non-trivial. As far as I understand you can't just sum up the weights for word towards specific topics (all weights should sum up to same number) but you may try to do this and see what happens.

Comment: I want that the user should be able to do this manually. I mean, which ever topic clusters they feel are irrelevant or duplicate, they should just be able to tell the machine to exclude those and the machine gradually learns that those are irrelevant or duplicate topic clusters. Is this possible to do?

Comment: @akrama81 I don't think so just due to the nature of topic modelling. It estimates topics based on matrix decomposition or based on probability of a word occurrence, trying to fit best model given a number of topics. If you 'merge' topics that means you are trying to create a union of a words which describe the topic and that will screw up the whole model since distributions or decomposition will not 'sum up to 1'.

Comment: @akrama81 the only thing I can come up with is to try to switch to LDA and based on user decision manually specify the frequency distribution for words in specific topics, but that will require some research

Comment: Hmm, I already tried LDa but that does not give relevant topic clusters for our dataset. Thanks for your insight though!

Comment: @akrama81 good luck. With NMF the issue is that it is a matrix decomposition thus it is much more difficult to understand how to decrease number of components and how to merge them. Maybe there is some research in this area but I didn't hear about it.

Comment: @akrama81 I spent some time reading about this topic (actually you asked a really good question) and updated my answer a bit.